# Moving picture in C#

Tags: c#, image

I need to write a code which moves a picture1 to the top of the screen after a click of a button. After pictire1 reaches the top 20 pixels of the screen must become invisible and make picture2 visible. This is my wrong code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int b = pictureBox1.Top;

    for (int i = b; i < 20; i--)
    {
        pictureBox1.Top = i;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);
    }

    if (pictureBox1.Top < 20)
    {
        pictureBox1.Visible = false;
        pictureBox2.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Any ideas how can it be fixed?

Comment: Which part of it is wrong? How is it behaving now compared to how you'd expect it to behave?

Comment: It has no errors, it's just not working. Nothing happens after I click the button.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code as part of the debugging process? It's anybody's guess upto now. It could even be that this event handler isn't being fired at all. Verify that it's being hit for starters, then step through and check the values of all your integers etc.

Comment: When you call `Sleep` the GUI has no chance of updating the layout, as the thread is blocked. Consider creating another thread to move the picture, or use a timer.

Comment: I thought, something going wrong in your for loop. you should debug your code step by step.

Comment: @AnuragJain No, debugging won't help here. The problem is in plain sight though.

Comment: Two obvious mistakes are that the condition i<20 should be i>20 and that right after updating Top you should call Application.DoEvents() to give the UI the opportunity to update itself. However, using a timer as BartozKP suggests is a better approach.

Comment: Was my answre not good enough? Because you first accepted my answer.

Comment: @DeeMac They're not acceptable if you decrement the loop variable.

Comment: @Noterezeck I've updated my answer to show you how to do this without blocking the UI or doing things like `Application.DoEvents`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems wrong:

```
for (int i = b; i < 20; i--)
{
    pictureBox1.Top = i;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);
}
```

This would loop while `i < 20`. From your code, however, one can see that if `Top == 20` is reached, you'd like to show another picture. So I guess that should be `i >= 20` and the `if` should be `Top <= 20`.

Also, you are not refreshing your display. Due to the loop and the `Sleep`, there will be no UI updates.

Add this, as Cobra_Fast suggests before the `Sleep`:

```
this.Invalidate();
this.Refresh();
```

To sum it up, the following should work (I've also slightly modified the code to make it clearer):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    while (pictureBox1.Top >= 20)
    {
        pictureBox1.Top = pictureBox1.Top - 1;
        this.Invalidate();
        this.Refresh();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);
    }

    // Here you KNOW that the picture box is at y-position 20, so there's not need
    // for the IF
    pictureBox1.Visible = false;
    pictureBox2.Visible = true;
}
```

---

The problem with the above code is that it blocks the UI. To keep it responsive, I'd use a timer as follows:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    // Create a threaded timer
    System.Timers.Timer animationTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    animationTimer.Interval = 20;
    animationTimer.AutoReset = false; // Only one Ping! We'll activate it if necessary
    animationTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(AnimationStep);
    animationTimer.Start();

    // Disable the button also, because we don't want another timer instance to
    // interfere with our running animation
    button1.Enabled = false;
}
```

Then, create the event that's called when the timer fires:

```
private void AnimationStep(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // The following code needs to be executed in the context of the UI thread.
    // We need to use this.Invoke in Forms or this.Dispatcher.Invoke in WPF
    this.Invoke((Action)delegate()
    {
        // Move picture. Note that we don't need to update the display here
        // because the UI thread gets time to do its work while the timer waits
        // to fire below
        if (pictureBox1.Top > 20)
            pictureBox1.Top--;

        // Show other picture maybe. I use <= here because initially, the
        // position of the picture box may already smaller than 20.
        if (pictureBox1.Top <= 20)
        {
            pictureBox1.Visible = false;
            pictureBox2.Visible = true;
        }

        // Or let the timer fire again if we still need to animate
        else
        {
            (source as System.Timers.Timer).Start();
        }
    }
}
```

This works as follows: A timer is created that fires once after 20ms. It then moves the picture up one pixel and then either shows the other picture if the animation is finished or starts the timer again for moving the picture up another pixel.

This keeps the UI responsive and still allows you to animate your picture. The downside is, the animation may not be as smooth as you might want it to be in case your windows is moved or other "work" needs be done by the UI thread.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but I tried the OP code. The Sleep statement makes the UI VERY slow to respond, but the the picture will update as soon as the Sleep is completed.

Comment: @jac This entire loop makes the UI **unable** to respond. It's not how I'd do it anyway, but it's his code.

Comment: Yes, since I need to move it to the top i need i>=20. And I really don't need that if. Thank you for the fast answer.

Comment: @Noterezeck I'll update my answer with a way to do it without blocking the UI. Give me a couple of minutes to write it down.

Answer (score 1):

What if initially `b` is greater than 20? The loop won't run because the condition in the loop is that `i < 20`. Because the loop is not ran, nothing will ever happen.

Consider changing the condition in your loop. You probably want the picture to move up, as you're reducing the `Top`-property. Let's say that initially the Top of pictureBox1 is 40. Following code will work:

```
while(pictureBox1.Top >= 20)
{
    pictureBox1.Top--;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);
    Invalidate();
    Refresh();
}
```

Since the Top is now less than 20, the if-statement can be omitted and you can just call:

```
pictureBox1.Visible = false;
pictureBox2.Visible = true;
```

Complete code:

```
while(pictureBox1.Top >= 20)
{
    pictureBox1.Top--;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);
    Invalidate();
    Refresh();
}

pictureBox1.Visible = false;
pictureBox2.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

After the `pictureBox1.Top` assignment, call:

```
this.Invalidate();
this.Refresh();
```

Assuming you're working with WinForms.